# Using Redux to pass data, this.props is still empty array

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to use Redux to fetch data from an action and show the properties of the JSON Object I get from the fetched API data in my component. But after following all the steps I've seen around the internet I still get an empty array when console.log(this.props)-ing in my component. This empty array seems to add items each time it's used, adding 'undefined' items to the array each time.

Oh well, my `action.js`:

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';


export const FETCH_RECIPES = 'FETCH_RECIPES';
const ROOT_URL = 'http://myapi/recipe/id/';

export function fetchRecipes(id) {
    const url = ROOT_URL + id;
    return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((request) => dispatch(fetchRecipesSuccess(request)))
    };
}

export function fetchRecipesSuccess(request) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_RECIPES,
        request
    };
}
```

and the reducer I'm importing my action into, `reducer_recipes.js`:

```
import { FETCH_RECIPES } from "../actions/index";

export function recipes (state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_RECIPES:
            return [action.request.data, ...state];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

My createStore:
`const createStoreWithMiddleware = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));`

Aaaaand finally, the relevant code snippets from my component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData(1);
}

render() {
    return (
        <h1>{console.log(this.props)}</h1>
)}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
return { recipes: state.recipes };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchData: (id) => dispatch(fetchRecipes(id))
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Recipe);
```

Where am I dropping the connection to this.props? Been banging my head at this for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see the data returned by the API request but I noticed one thing below

When you are accessing the state, you are accessing it as an object with an array properties, recipes

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { recipes: state.recipes };
}
```

But you are returning an array with [],

```
import { FETCH_RECIPES } from "../actions/index";

export function recipes (state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_RECIPES:
            return [action.request.data, ...state];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Perhaps you could try

```
return {...state, action.request.data};
```

or

```
return {...state, recipes: action.request.data};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that didn't help either :( When checking in my action, the fetch is going through and grabbing the data, but I'm guessing it's getting dropped in either my reducer or in the component. Any more ideas?

Comment: I see, could you show me what is retrieved in `action.request.data`? Please mask the data if it is sensitive.

Comment: I finally got the fetch to work -- if I use `action.request` without `.data` in my reducer it shows the data. I have a follow-up question though as I'm still having issues:

In my component, if I `console.log(this.props.recipes)` I get an array of all recipes fetched. If I `console.log(this.props.recipes[0]` I get one of these objects, with different values in it, like Description, Name and Id. If I then do `console.log(this.props.recipes[0].Name` -- it says Name is undefined, even though I can see there is a value there from my earlier console.logs. What could cause this?

Comment: Glad to know that your issue is resolved.
1. Is "Name" a valid attribute for recipe, or "name", because it is case sensitive 

OR

2. Is recipes[0] an object or another array with an object in it?

Comment: Yes, the "Name"-attribute is correct so that doesn't seem to be the problem. And recipes[0] is a single object with values in it. Very weird that I can't access it...

Comment: I see... do you mind to paste your information of this.props.recipes here, so I could try it out on my side.

Comment: Try console.log(this.props.recipes[0]["Name"])

Comment: I actually got it working by changing my reducer to `return action.request`.  Although, I'm not changing depending on current state now, am I?

Comment: I see, if return `action.request` will directly make it becomes the state. If `action.request` contains a `recipes` array object, `state.recipes[0].Name` will be the recipe name.